# Creating a new Laravel 4 model class with a string variable

Tags: php, class, model, laravel, laravel-4

**TL;DR is at the end to cut to the chase.**

I have a lot of belongsTo() models that can have any number of records, and I'm trying to bind them to an edit form.  I have the following foreach that creates the form elements:

```
@foreach ($department->department_10 as $key => $value)
    {{ Form::select(
        'department_10['.(isset($value->pk_department_10)?$value->pk_department_10:0).']',
        $department_10_opts,
        (isset($value->department_10)?$value->department_10:''),
        array('class'=>'form-control input-md department_10', 'placeholder'=>'Other Types of Service')) }}
@endforeach
```

Since there can be 0 records (rows?) that belong to the model, to simplify my `@foreach`, I wanted to create a "blank" instance of the model.  Additionally, because I'm going to have to deal with about 70 more cases like this, I created a function that would create the new blank model.  Here's the function (in my controller for lack of a better place):

```
function mkBlankModel($parentModel, $newModel){
    if(count($parentModel->$newModel) === 0){
        $parentModel->$newModel[0] = new $newModel();
        $parentModel->$newModel[0]->fk_department = $parentModel->pk_department;
        $parentModel->$newModel[0]->$newModel = '';
    }
    return $parentModel;
}
```

When I run it, I don't get any errors, but I do get unexpected results and I can't really make sense of them:

Test Step 1) View the edit page while loading a record with 2 department_10's.  It works as expected; loads two fields properly.

Test Step 2)  View the edit page while loading a record with 0 department_10's.  The page loads but without any fields.  Because apparently my function didn't work, so I verify by dumping `dump($department->$department_10)` and it confirms this.

Test Step 3) I replace the `$parentModel->$newModel[0]` with `$parentModel->department_10[0]` like so:

```
function mkBlankModel($parentModel, $newModel){
if(count($parentModel->$newModel) === 0){
    $parentModel->department_10[0] = new $newModel();
    $parentModel->department_10[0]->fk_department = $parentModel->pk_department;
    $parentModel->department_10[0]->$newModel = '';
}
return $parentModel;
}
```

And both scenarios (with records and without) work just fine.  So my problem likely isn't Laravel specific, but I'm just curious how I can accomplish this.

**TL;DR:**

I'm trying to create a model instance for a parent model, if one doesn't exist, so a blank field will be created by my `@foreach` loop in my `edit.blade.php's` form.  I can do this just fine if I manually spell out the model's name when creating it, but since I'll be doing this frequently, I'd prefer to define the class, and populate it with a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out;  I needed to wrap the $newModel in curly-brackets:

```
function mkBlankModel($parentModel, $newModel){
    if(count($parentModel->$newModel) === 0){
        $parentModel->{$newModel}[0] = new $newModel();
        $parentModel->{$newModel}[0]->fk_department = $parentModel->pk_department;
        $parentModel->{$newModel}[0]->$newModel = '';
    }
    return $parentModel;
}
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex